# How does this code from Eloquent JS determine the dominant writing direction?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I’m picking up *Eloquent JavaScript* and the answer to [this higher-order function exercise](https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html) has me stumped:

```js
function characterScript(code) {
  for (let script of SCRIPTS) {
    if (script.ranges.some(([from, to]) => {
      return code >= from && code < to;
    })) {
      return script;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

// takes a test function and tells you whether that function
// returns true for any of the elements in the array

function countBy(items, groupName) {
  let counts = [];
  for (let item of items) {
    let name = groupName(item);
    let known = counts.findIndex(c => c.name == name);
    if (known == -1) {
      counts.push({name, count: 1});
    } else {
      counts[known].count++;
    }
  }
  return counts;
}

// returns an array of objects, each of which names a group
// and tells you the number of elements that were found in that group

function dominantDirection(text) {
  let scripts = countBy(text, char => {
    let script = characterScript(char.codePointAt(0));
    return script ? script.direction : "none";
  }).filter(({name}) => name != "none");
 
  if (scripts.length == 0) return "ltr";
  
  return scripts.reduce((a, b) => a.count > b.count ? a : b).name;
}

console.log(dominantDirection("Hello!"));
// → ltr
console.log(dominantDirection("Hey, مساء الخير"));
// → rtl
```

This code returns the dominant writing direction in a large data set that looks like the following:

```js
[
  {
    name: "Coptic",
    ranges: [[994, 1008], [11392, 11508], [11513, 11520]],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: -200,
    living: false,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coptic_alphabet"
  },
  // …
]
```

I understand how a loop with the `some` method is used to find any arrays in which the character code returns `true`.
I can’t get my head around how the `countBy` function or the `dominantDirection` function lead to the result shown at the bottom.

**A breakdown of the two functions and how they lead to the correct result would be appreciated immensely!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s easier to understand if you inspect some intermediate results.
Add a `console.log` to see what `scripts` returns, remove `.name` to see what the result of the `reduce` call is:

```js
function dominantDirection(text) {
  const scripts = countBy(text, (char) => {
      const script = characterScript(char.codePointAt(0));
    
      return (script
        ? script.direction
        : "none"
      );
    })
      .filter(({name}) => name !== "none");
 
  if(scripts.length === 0){
    return "ltr";
  }
  
  console.log(scripts); // What is the result of the `countBy` function?
  
  return scripts.reduce((a, b) => (a.count > b.count
    ? a
    : b)); // What is the object that the `name` property comes from?
}
```

---

Now `dominantDirection("Hello!")` will log `scripts` as

```js
[
  { name: "ltr", count: 5 }
]
```

​
and the result will also be

```js
{ name: "ltr", count: 5 }
```

And `dominantDirection("Hey, مساء الخير")` will log `scripts` as

```js
[
  { name: "ltr", count: 3 },
  { name: "rtl", count: 9 }
]
```

with the result

```js
{ name: "rtl", count: 9 }
```

---

The `scripts` array comes from the `countBy` call which returns a count of how many code points there are in the string, for each script direction.
It tries to find the corresponding script from each of the `SCRIPTS` by comparing which of the `ranges` the `codePoint` falls into and getting the corresponding `direction` property.

This higher-order function `countBy` accepts the arguments `items` and `groupName`.
`dominantDirection` calls `countBy` with two arguments and stores its result in `scripts`.

- `items` is an iterable value, in this case a string (of code points): that’s just the input string, e.g. `"Hey, مساء الخير"`. From this value, individual items (code points) will be grouped into “buckets” and counted separately.
- `groupName` is a function that returns the name of the “bucket” that a single code point (e.g. a character) belongs to (based on the code point itself): in this case, it’s the arrow function `char => {`…`}` which calls `characterScript` with a single `char`’s code point and returns the corresponding script object (which you say you understand). It then gets the script’s `direction`, for example `"ltr"` for the `{ name: "Coptic",`…`}` object from your example (or `"none"` if no script object can be found).

As an aside, `groupName` isn’t a good name, as it expects a function, but the name implies a string.
Maybe `groupNameFromItem` is better.

As `countBy` iterates over the string (`for (let item of items)`), this function (originally `char => {`…`}`) is called and assigned to `name` (`let name = groupName(item);`).
Since `char => {`…`}` returns a script’s `direction`, `name` becomes either `"ltr"`, `"rtl"`, or `"none"` — that’s the name of the “bucket”.
The array `counts` is populated with objects like `{ name: "ltr", count: 1 }`.
If the next code point also comes from an `ltr` script, this object is found using `findIndex` and its `count` incremented using `++`.

This populated array is then returned (which is what `scripts` refers to inside `dominantDirection`).

The `reduce` is easily explained: `a` and `b` are objects from one of the `scripts` arrays.
If `a.count` is higher than `b.count`, `a` is returned, otherwise `b` is returned; the returned object is then used for the next comparison, or, if nothing else needs to be compared, returned as a result.
So the `reduce` call finds the object with the maximum `count`.
In the original code, only the `name` is returned at the end, not the entire object.

---

To summarize:

`text` is a string that consists of code points from different scripts.
`countBy` takes `text`, iterates over the code points, calls `groupName` to get the “bucket name” for the current code point, populates the `counts` array (named `scripts`, outside of the function) with `{ name, count }` entries that tell you that *`count` many code points come from scripts in the `name` direction*.
Then a `reduce` looks for the maximum `count` among these entries and its `name` is returned.

---

Two more things:

- > I understand how a loop with the `some` method is used to find any arrays in which the character code returns `true`.

  The character code itself doesn’t return `true`.
  The `some` call returns `true` if the code point `code` falls into any of the ranges between `from` (inclusive) and `to` (exclusive), or `false`, otherwise.
- The chapter is about higher-order functions, so it’s important to understand how the `groupName` parameter in `function countBy(items, groupName){`…`}` works.
  I’m not quite sure how familiar you are with this concept, but here’s a simpler example where odd and even numbers are counted with some explanatory comments:

  ```js
  const countOddAndEvenNumbers = (iterable) => {
      const oddOrEvenBucketFromNumber = (number) => (number % 2 === 0 ? "even" : "odd"); // This is the function that distinguishes odd and even numbers.

      return countGroups(iterable, oddOrEvenBucketFromNumber); // The distinguishing function is passed to `countGroups` to be used.
    },
    countGroups = (iterable, bucketNameFromItem) => {
      const result = {}; // Usually counting is done with hash maps, e.g. objects or Maps, instead of arrays.

      for(let item of iterable){
        const bucketName = bucketNameFromItem(item); // Generic way of `const bucketName = (item % 2 === 0 ? "even" : "odd")`; acts as `const bucketName = oddOrEvenBucketFromNumber(item)`, but with no own knowledge of what odd or even numbers are: it’s entirely separated and knows nothing about the implementation of the function.

        result[bucketName] = (result[bucketName] ?? 0) + 1; // Increment entry `bucketName` by one. If it doesn’t exist, initialize it to `0` first.
      }

      return result;
    };

  countOddAndEvenNumbers([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]); // { "even": 3, "odd": 5 }
  ```